# appium how to override capabilities

Tags: java, appium

Any ideas on the following.

My standard capabilities are set to open my native application.

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
```

This is defined in a method with @BeforeMethod annotation (TestNG)

I have one specific test I want to start in Chrome. How can I acheive this ? Can I override in some way the capabilities for one specific test ?

Answer (score 0):

TestNG lets you pass parameters directly to your test methods in two different ways:

- With testng.xml
- With Data Providers

Consider this feature and maybe implement your own Data Provider which will provide separate configuration to your specific test method. In this way you even could prepare and start appium server with different configuration and capabilities for each test method

Answer (score 0):

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
<test name="Test1">
    <parameter name="Device" value="ABCD" />
    <parameter name="Port" value="4723" />
        <classes>
            <class name="" />
            <methods>

            </methods>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite> 

use following annotations on your desired capability method and pass them in desired capability
@BeforeTest / @Beforemethod / @Beforeclass
@Parameters({"Device","Port"})
public void desiredcapability(string Device,string Port)
{


}
```

Comment: I already use parameters in my testng file to specify device id, platform, device name.... But these are applied to all the testmethods I run.

My problem is that 99% of my test methods are ran on my native app, but I have 1 test that start with opening a browser and halfway it opens my native application.

i can't add capability 'browserName' to my setup method, because then the rest of my tests will fail, cause it always opens my browser. Seems that capability has priority on App capabilities.
So now looking for a solution without adapting my '@beforemethod  which works for 99%.

Comment: I tried this                                                                                              
when we need to launch browser we can pass chrome in browser parameter through testng capabilities.setCapability("browserName","chrome");                       
when we do not need to launch browser we can pass empty space "" in browser parameter through testng capabilities.setCapability("browserName","");  I have tested this it is working fine for me.